# Limit columns from QuickBooks Online API Customer Query

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I know I can do something like:

`SELECT * FROM Customer`

which returns the following objects.

- Active
- AlternatePhone
- Balance
- BalanceWithJobs
- BillAddr
- BillWithParent
- CompanyName
- CurrencyRef
- DefaultTaxCodeRef
- DisplayName
- FullyQualifiedName
- Id
- Job
- MetaData
- PreferredDeliveryMethod
- PrimaryEmailAddr
- PrimaryPhone
- PrintOnCheckName
- ShipAddr
- SyncToken
- Taxable

I tried limiting my query to:

`SELECT Id FROM Customer` which worked great, but for some reason I cannot do:

`SELECT ShipAddr FROM Customer`.  No data is returned.

I've learned `SELECT DisplayName, Id FROM Customer` works but nothing else does.

Is there a way I can request the following data only and nothing else:

`SELECT AlternativePhone, BillAddr, CompanyName, DisplayName, Id, PrimaryEmailAddr, PrimaryPhone, ShipAddr FROM Customer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think fetching only selective fields is supported for all fields.
You can try your queries on API explorer and see if get the resultset you want. Else, please consider it as non-supported.
You will have to get the full response in that case then and use the selected fields/properties.